# In Asp.net, how browser knows a textbox is registered with server side TextChanged event?

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I evaluate asp.net control events, I am not able to identify how the browser is aware of asp.net textbox is subscribed to serverside textchanged event or not. When I look the server generated HTML code, there is not information about the TextChanged event.

**ASP.Net Declaration**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtInput" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtInput_OnTextChanged"
    AutoPostBack="false" />
```

**Server Generated HTML Code**

```
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$txtInput" type="text" value="SivaText Input ChangedText Input Changed.V ChangedText Input Changed.V Changed" id="MainContent_txtInput">
```

Answer (score 2):

The server encodes the state of all input elements in the hidden field named `__VIEWSTATE`. Have a look at the rendered HTML and you can see it in the `<div class="aspNetHidden">` element somewhere on the top.

When the form is submitted, both values from the HTML input form elements and the value in the hidden input element `__VIEWSTATE` are submitted together. For each input element the server compares the values submitted via the corresponding form element (e.g. `<input type="text">` with the value encoded in the view state. If they are different, a `TextChanged` event is triggered for the server-side `TextBox` control.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET generates javascript that attaches to the `onchange` event causing a postback.

Part of the data sent in the postback/viewdata/viewstate includes what caused the postback with a translation from the client side event to the server side event.

Don't forget - ASP.NET renders normal HTML - on the browser it is just a `<textarea>` or `<input type="text">`, after all.

Comment: Can we able to see server generated javascript codes?. Since, when I view the server generated hmtl file I am not able to see the javascript codes.

Comment: Use the developer tools of the browser. Of course you can see the JS, given that the browser needs to see it.